# Run view in command

Tags: django, django-views, django-commands

I have a view to download a file. I want to create a command to be able to call this view and download the file in a certain folder.

```
class DownloadFile(View):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        ...
```

How can I run this view in a custom command and save the file locally?

Comment: in command function, do a http request to that url via localhost.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create a Django Management Command (and not a function), create a new python file under

*"Your-Django-App -> management -> commands -> your_custom_command.py"*

Then, create a Command class. You can define here where you want to download your files. Example:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    media_folder = os.getcwd() + '/media/'
    private_folder = os.getcwd() + '/private/'

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    # insert your code here
```

You can execute this command from the terminal:

```
python manage.py your_custom_command
```

Or you can execute it from your code. More information here on Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code

Here you can read more about management commands:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/